# S3DistCp job failure: -- dest doesn't match

Tags: java, hadoop, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I am trying to use s3DistCp to combine some small files in 1 S3 folder to another S3 folder.  Script is something like the following:

```
elastic-mapreduce --jobflow j-33EDUGSQCN0PZ --jar \
/home/hadoop/lib/emr-s3distcp-1.0.jar \
--args '--src,s3://li-test/data, \
--dest,s3://li-test/result, \
--groupBy,[0-9]*,\
--targetSize,128'
```

But I am getting java.lang.RuntimeException error as following.  Help is needed.  Thanks!

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Argument  \
--dest doesn't match.
at emr.hbase.options.Options.parseArguments(Options.java:75)
at emr.hbase.options.Options.parseArguments(Options.java:57)
at com.amazon.elasticmapreduce.s3distcp.S3DistCp$S3DistCpOptions.
(S3DistCp.java:124)
at com.amazon.elasticmapreduce.s3distcp.S3DistCp.run(S3DistCp.java:545)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:65)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:79)
at com.amazon.elasticmapreduce.s3distcp.Main.main(Main.java:13)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at 
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:187)

Answer (score 1):

After decompiling the emr-s3distcp-1.0.jar that is stored in the emr cluster's /home/hadoop/lib folder I found that the java code is looking for the parameters to be of this style:

`--src=s3://BUCKET-NAME/139kb-input --dest=s3://BUCKET-NAME/139kb-output`

The specific difference between this line and the documentation is the use of '=' instead of a ',' between the argument and the argument's value.

This is the if statement java is using:

`if (argument.length() >= this.arg.length() + 1 && argument.substring(0, this.arg.length() + 1).equals(this.arg + "="))`

where this.arg is "--src" and argument is "--src=s3://BUCKET-NAME/139kb-input"

CAVEAT: This was the case when creating the step through the web interface as a custom jar. Creating the step from the command line works with using a ',' as the documentation says instead of a '='.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a silly mistake. It is reading the following as to be a S3DistCp command line option :

`\ --dest`

So instead of trying to break you command into several line, why don't you give a command like follows:

```
elastic-mapreduce --jobflow j-33EDUGSQCN0PZ --jar /home/hadoop/lib/emr-s3distcp-1.0.jar --args '--src,s3://li-test/data, --dest,s3://li-test/result, --groupBy,[0-9]*,--targetSize,128'
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message says `\ --dest` doesn't match, so that means it thinks the `\` is part of the argument. Try this:

```
elastic-mapreduce --jobflow j-33EDUGSQCN0PZ --jar \
/home/hadoop/lib/emr-s3distcp-1.0.jar \
--args '--src,s3://li-test/data, --dest,s3://li-test/result, --groupBy,[0-9]*, --targetSize,128'
```